# Recursive PHP function that copies multidimensional array but replaces empty values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that could be any size or depth.  I'm basically trying replace empty values with a value but only in certain cases.  Here is an example of the array, it's quite large but I want to illustrate my point well:

```
[field_ter] => 
[field_title] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 
            )

    )

[field_firstnames] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => test9
            )

    )

[field_birth] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 
            )

    )

[field_postal] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 
            )

    )

[group_certificates] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_delta] => 0
                [field_cert_details] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [field_cert_issuedate] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                            )

                    )

                [field_cert_expiry] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                            )

                    )

                [field_cert_issue_country] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [field_cert_limits] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [_delta] => 1
                [field_cert_details] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [field_cert_issuedate] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                            )

                    )

                [field_cert_expiry] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                            )

                    )

                [field_cert_issue_country] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [field_cert_limits] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

What I'm trying to do is find any element in the array that is empty, then replace the empty value with a value.  I have an array of exceptions where the empty element is not replaced.  This is the function I'm working on at the moment:

```
function check_empty(&$array) { 
    $exceptions = array('changed', 'form_build_id','date', 'status', 'op');
    // This is the array we will return at the end of the function
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            check_empty($value);
        }
        elseif ($value == '' && !in_array($key, $exceptions)) {
            $new_array[$key] = '$$$';
        }
        else {
            $new_array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Could someone help me tweak my function or point me in the direction of a better way?  I tried array_walk_recursive but it doesn't work with my arrays.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on how to format your question. Here, we use something called Markdown in lieu of usual HTML. There are some toolbar icons just above the textarea that can help you with the formatting. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of the recursive `check_empty`:

```
function check_empty($array) { 
    $exceptions = array('changed', 'form_build_id','date', 'status', 'op');
    // This is the array we will return at the end of the function
    $new_array = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $new_array[$key] = check_empty($value);
        }
        elseif ($value == '' && !in_array($key, $exceptions)) {
            $new_array[$key] = '$$$';
        }
        else {
            $new_array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much.  A bit of an amateur mistake!

Answer (score 2):

```
if(is_array($value)) {
  check_empty($value);
}
```

Here you don't return resulting value to anywhere. Probably that's the problem